# Can't seem to disable on-screen navigation buttons. How do the other apps do this?

Tags: android, root

I can hide the whole system interface just fine (though that kills the wallpaper for whatever reason) by killing its service and restarting when the user wants. What I can't seem to do however, is hide ONLY the on-screen navigation keys down in the bottom, leaving only the top notification bar left.

How would I go about doing so?

EDIT 1: And just to add, I *have* looked for open sourced apps for this to no avail, however.

EDIT 2: Yes my device is rooted and the app is root-only.

Comment: You should include that you know that you need a rooted phone, people will start doing it to you.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to do this in your app or do you have a rooted device that you want to do this to (perhaps for display purposes or something)?

Comment: @Ali Both. My app is rooted and lets people change resolution either independently or whenever HDMI is detected. Right now I want people to be able to disable the bottom navbars as it, depending on DPI setting, goes on the side if they do not set it up correctly. I thought it would be a nice update to push. I just can't seem to find any sources to learn from...

Comment: If you use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE, buttons are turned into the dots and it's still possible to touch them and use as usual. Using SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION hides the buttons, but when users touches the screen they again appear and can be used.

Comment: Example - 1. Usage: `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);`2. Alternative to the first: `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);`.

Comment: @g00dy It will have to stay that way permanently until the user decides to re-enable them again. So that way does not work for me, sadly. :/

Comment: @Carl - Well, the thing I posted here is the only way to interact with the visibility of those buttons - you must know for sure that **they can not be disabled**, this will be a security issue if a user can't have an exit from an application.

Comment: @g00dy Surely you are wrong. Take GMD Auto Hide for example. This app lets you hide the softkeys just fine with a single swipe. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmd.hidesoftkeys&hl=en

Comment: Yeah, that's a comment from before your EDITS. On rooted phones it is possible.